# CSV to Python Dictionary with multiple lists for one key

Tags: python, csv

So I have a csv file formatted like this

```
data_a,dataA,data1,data11
data_b,dataB,data1,data12
data_c,dataC,data1,data13
 , , ,
data_d,dataD,data2,data21
data_e,dataE,data2,data22
data_f,dataF,data2,data23
HEADER1,HEADER2,HEADER3,HEADER4
```

The column headers are at the bottom, and I want the third column to be the keys. You can see that the third column is the same value for each of the two blocks of data and these blocks of data are separated by empty values, so I want to store the 3 rows of values to this 1 key and also disregard some columns such as column 4. This is my code right now

```
#!usr/bin/env python

import csv

with open("example.csv") as f:
    readCSV = csv.reader(f)

    for row in readCSV:
            # disregard separating rows
            if row[2] != '':
                    myDict = {row[2]:[row[0],row[1]]}
            print(myDict)
```

What I basically want is that when I call

```
print(myDict['data2'])
```

I get

```
{[data_d,dataD][data_e,dataE][data_f,dataF]}
```

I tried editing my if loop to

```
if row[2] == 'data2':
    myDict = {'data2':[row[0],row[1]]}
```

and just make an if for every individual key, but I don't think this will work either way.

Comment: What is your problem at the moment? What output are you getting that is "incorrect"?

Comment: @asongtoruin My problem is that I have no idea how to achieve what I want to do. My current code just loops through my csv file and replaces the value and keys in my dictionary with the next row of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current method, you probably want a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). This is a dictionary-like object that provides a default value if the key doesn't already exist. So in your case, we set this up to be a list, and then for each row we loop through, we append the values in columns 0 and 1 to this list as a tuple, like so:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)

with open("example.csv") as f:
    readCSV = csv.reader(f)

    for row in readCSV:
        # disregard separating rows
        if row[2] != '':
            data[row[2]].append((row[0], row[1]))

print(data)
```

With the example provided, this prints a `defaultdict` with the following entries:

```
{'data1': [('data_a', 'dataA'), ('data_b', 'dataB'), ('data_c', 'dataC')], 'data2': [('data_d', 'dataD'), ('data_e', 'dataE'), ('data_f', 'dataF')]}
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I wanted! Thank you very much!

Comment: One question, how would I call only 1 key, say I only wanted to call data1's values?

Comment: @JimKM exactly as you would with a "normal" dictionary - `data['data1']`

Comment: @songtoruin how do I access a specific element in a list for a specific key? I've tried (data[ 'data1' ][1]) to get the second element out but that doesn't work.

Comment: @JimKM It should work - `data['data1'][1]` will get you the element at index 1 in the list returned by the key `'data1'` - i.e. the _tuple_ `('data_b', 'dataB')`

Comment: yes it returns the tuple, but I only want the value of the 1st index, so I only want to be returned 'dataB'

Comment: @JimKM okay - so then it's `data['data1'][1][1]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a super Python geek, but I would suggest to use pandas (`import pandas as pd`). So you load data with `pd.read_csv(file, header)`. With `header` you can specify the row you want to be a header and then it's much much easier to manipulate with the dataset (e.g. dropping the vars (`del df['column_name']`), creating dictionaries, etc).

Here is documentation to `pd.read_csv`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html